# Continuity in piecewise function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity, piecewise-continuity

I need to study the continuity of this function:

$$
f(x, y) = 
  \begin{cases}
    \frac{4y x^2}{x^4+ y^2}, & \text{if } (x, y) \neq (0, 0)\\
    0, & \text{if } (x, y) = (0, 0)
  \end{cases}
$$

When I study the directional limits, specifically $y = px ^ 2$, I get the limit different than zero. But when I draw the function in 3D I see that the point (0.0) it is continuous.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @flawr I do not know if I have calculated the directional limit well or I have not looked at the graph correctly.

Comment: Well what limit did you get?

Comment: @flawr limit of 4x ^ 4 / 2x ^ 4 = 2 if y=x^2.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PEhJc why do you think this is continuous at the origin?

Comment: @user2723984 what program u use? ty for the graph.

Comment: It's called Grapher, it's preinstalled on every Apple computer, I don't think you can get it on other computers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us consider the limit of $f$ on a curve $y=px^2$. We can parametrize this curve by $t \mapsto (pt^2,t)$ and

$$\lim_{t\to 0} f(x(t),y(t)) = \lim \frac{4pt^4}{t^4+pt^4} = \frac{4p}{1+p}$$

So for $p=0$ the limit is actually $0$, but for $p=1$ we already get the limit $2$. Since these two limits are not equal, the function $f$ cannot be continuous at $0$.

Even if you plot this function at a low resolution in the domain $[-1,1]\times [-1,1]$, you can see that the limit on the curves $y=px^2$ is not zero for $p\neq 0$.